# Simplest way to send data to and from FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I've got a Basys2 board and need to transfer data between the FPGA and my PC(linux, transfer in both directions).

It doesn't have to be fast, but it should be easy to implement and not take up to many gates. What would you recommend? I2C, rs232, USB or something else?

Comment: The Basys2 board is from Digilent and comes with a Adept software stack. This software offers you simple I/O and data transfer functions. Please read the Digilent manuals and tutorial on how to use Adept. Another simple way would be to use a USB-UART bridge, but the Basys2 has no integrated bridge chip.

Answer (score 6):

USB is much too complicated
SPI and I2C can't be interfaced directly to your PC.

A serial interface (UART) is quite simple to implement in a FPGA.
You just need to add a level-converter (e.g. MAX3232 3.3V ↔ RS232) hardware.
In case your PC doesn't have a RS232 interface you can add an off-the-shelf RS232-USB converter (5 EUR) or use a ready-made 3.3V ↔ RS232 level-converter with integrated USB converter.